# Django Rest Framework Send Image in Email

Tags: python, django, email, django-rest-framework

Hello I have faced an Issue regarding sending email In django rest API.
The Idea is user sends email and Uploads image from serializer part and I want to send same image to users Email. But I am not getting image in email.

here is the code I have been working.

```
models.py
class Mail(BaseModel):
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=mail_image_to)
    email = models.EmailField()
```

below is my serializer

```
class MailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Mail
        fields = '__all__'


class AddMailSerializer(MailSerializer):
    class Meta(MailSerializer.Meta):
        fields = (
            'full_name',
            'image',
            'email',
        )
```

views.py

```
class AddMailView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """
    Use this endpoint to add mail
    """
    serializer_class = serializers.AddMailSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return AddMailUseCase(serializer=serializer).execute()
```

I usually write my rest of code in usecase.py

```
class AddMailUseCase:
    def __init__(self, serializer):
        self.serializer = serializer
        self.data = serializer.validated_data

    def execute(self):
        self._factory()

    def _factory(self):
        self._mail = Mail(**self.data)
        self._mail.save()
        SendEmail(
            context={
                "fullname": self.data['full_name'],
                'image': self.data['image']
            }
        ).send(to=[self.data['email']])
```

I am using `django-templated-mail 1.1.1` to send email here is my rest of code.

```
from templated_mail.mail import BaseEmailMessage


class SendEmail(BaseEmailMessage):
    template_name = 'email.html'
```

and finally my `email.html`

```
{% load i18n %}

{% block subject %}
{% blocktrans %}Email Successfully Sent {% endblocktrans %}
{% endblock subject %}

{% block text_body %}
{% blocktrans %}You're receiving this email because you recently registered  to our website.{% endblocktrans %}

{% trans "Your submitted details are as follow" %}

{% endblock text_body %}

{% block html_body %}
{% blocktrans %}
<p>hello {{ fullname }}</p>{% endblocktrans %}
{% blocktrans %}
<img src="{{ image }}" alt="email-image">

<p>{% trans "Thanks for using our site!" %}</p>

{% endblock html_body %}
```

any help regarding this issue?
the email I got is as below image is not loading
[image]

Comment: Can you check the image link in your email ?

Comment: there is no anything sadly I tried inspecting and it is empty

Answer (score 0):

instead of using

```
<img src="{{ image }}" alt="email-image">
```

use

```
<img src="{{ image.url }}" alt="email-image">
```

and in your URL.py add

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: unfortunately email needs host too so this wont solve the problem